# Custom Post Type permalink not working on new posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, permalinks

I've been struggling for a while with this and would really appreciate any help.

I have a custom post type 'venues' on a site I'm working on. I have the permalinks setup so they are as follows: http://www.site-name.com/venues/venue-name

This has worked fine 'til now. But whenever I add a new venue the permalink on it doesn't seem to work - it simply goes to a blank white page. I'm unsure how to go about fixing this since it's working on all the previous venue entries.

Below is the relevant code for the Custom Post Type:

```
function venues () {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Venues', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Venue', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'venue' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Venue' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Venue' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Venue' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Venues' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Venues' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Venues' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No Venues found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Venues found in the Trash' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Venues'
);
$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
                'taxonomies'            => array('category'),

    'description'   => 'This is where all of the venues in the Find Us section are held',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'thumbnail'),
    'has_archive'   => true,
                'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'venue'),

);
register_post_type( 'venues', $args );
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried updating your permalink by just visiting the permalink settings page and clicking "Update"

Comment: Yep, no luck. Also tried changing the permalink structure to all of the different options.